# Joomla - How to apply template changes to pages using the changed template?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

An application that I need to work on is running on Joomla! 2.5.8. For the life of me, I cannot find a way to edit the main file (index.php) of a template and see those changes on the page using the template.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the Joomla backend.

1. Go to **Extensions** >> **Template Manager**
2. Click on the **Templates** tab
3. Click on **TEMPLATE_NAME Details and Files**
4. Then on the left hand side, click on **Edit main page template**.

This will open a page allowing you to edit the index.php file for you template. Do note though that this is to edit your template and **not** extensions.

Hope this helps

Comment: Already did this, but the changes are not visible on the page (i.e. article) using the template. :(

Comment: The article is part of **com_content** which is an extension, therefore editing the index.php file for you template will not change this as mentioned in my answer :) You will have to perform a [Template Override](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core) for this